# Joining two large tables on the latest data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two large tables -

**First table**

```
claim   dx      patient     date
106551  K8010   156210139   2019-10-01
10611   K8011   156210139   2019-11-31
106111  K8111   156210139   2020-10-30
```

**Second table**

```
claim   patient     from_dt     days
106551  156210139   2019-09-11  22
101151  156210139   2019-09-19  23
10655   156210139   2018-01-01  29
```

(There are other columns in both of these tables but I have not included them here).

How do I write a query joining these tables on `patient` such that the latest claim from 90 days prior is included in the results.

For example, this is the output I am looking for -

```
patient     date          from_dt
156210139   2019-10-01    2019-09-19
156210139   2019-11-31    2019-09-19
156210139   2020-10-30
```

I already have a query that works but it takes 2 hours to finish so I am hoping someone has a more optimized way of writing the query to get the desired output.

Comment: show us your query

Comment: And the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, FORMAT TEXT) for it.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two options:

1. Use `ROW_NUMBER()` in a left join.
2. Use a lateral join that `LIMIT`s the joined rows to a maximum of 1.

You can see the first option below:

```
select patient, date, from_dt
from (
  select f.patient, f.date, s.from_dt,
    row_number() over(partition by f.patient order by s.from_dt desc) as rn
  from first_table f
  left join second_table s on s.patient = f.patient
    and s.from_dt between f.date - interval '90 day' and f.date
) x
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good opportunity to try a `lateral` join:

```
select f.*, s.*
from first f left join lateral
     (select s.*
      from second s
      where s.patient = f.patient and
            s.from_dt <= f.date and
            s.from_dt > f.date - interval '90 day'
      order by s.from_dt desc
      limit 1
    ) s
    on 1=1
```